# Whats the best way to start a long Python process from php running on apache?

Tags: php, python, cakephp, background-process

I have an apache server running a cakephp project.

There is this python code that I need to run which takes about 90min to 120 min to complete fully.

I need to invoke this script from python. I tried exec and passthru, nothing happens.

Also I need a way to find out when the python code is done so that my php code can go forward and continue some work..
How do I achieve this?

Comment: I suppose here is two ways: first - start python code as separated server (rpc, rest, whatever you want) or second - start this code via cron task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Long Running Background Task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802681/php-long-running-background-task)

Answer (score 0):

Did you [try to search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802681/php-long-running-background-task) before asking? There are plenty of solutions and tutorials for that kind of task.

Your question is basically a duplicate of this one [PHP - Long Running Background Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802681/php-long-running-background-task). So just see the answer there.

> One option to background the task is to use fork. However, I strongly
>   suggest using a proper job manager like gearman (see php extensions
>   also), or queue, like amqp or zmq, to handle these tasks more cleanly.
>   Which one is more suitable for your use case, I'll let you decide.